# How do I correctly use the Ruby Tk module?

Tags: ruby

I'm currently trying to create a basic GUI application in Ruby using the Tk module. Whenever I attempt to `require` the module (as `tk` or `tcltklib`), I get the following `LoadError`:

```
LoadError (126: The specified module could not be found. - C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/tk-0.2.0/lib/tcltklib.so)
```

---

Currently, I have:

- Installed Tcl (ActiveTcl) from the [ActiveState website](https://www.activestate.com/products/activetcl/downloads/), specifically the `8.5.18.0` version for Windows (x86).
- Installed Ruby with [RubyInstaller for Windows](https://rubyinstaller.org/), specifically `Ruby+Devkit 2.5.3-1 (x86)`. The MSYS2 development toolchain was also selected to be installed, and all 3 components were chosen during `ridk install`.
- Run `gem install tk`. The RubyInstaller changelog notes that, [as of version `2.4.1-1`, `tk` is no longer part of the standard library but can still be installed with `gem install tk`](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2/blob/master/CHANGELOG-2.4.md#removed-2).
- Attempted to `require 'tk'` and `require 'tcltklib'` in IRB and received the error above.

---

When running the following through IRB

```rb
require 'tk'
```

The output is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        8: from C:/Ruby25/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
        7: from (irb):3
        6: from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
        5: from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
        4: from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
        3: from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/tk-0.2.0/lib/tk.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        2: from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        1: from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
LoadError (126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/tk-0.2.0/lib/tcltklib.so)
```

The referenced file (`C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/tk-0.2.0/lib/tcltklib.so`) does in fact exist though and this error seems different to the one output when requiring a non-existent module.

---

There seems to be very little information on this specific error, in fact, the only related things I could find were 10 year old posts on the Ruby forum which didn't yield much information.